# Position logo in same line as text + able to resize bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make text and image stay in one line. Tryed to use some codes from questions asked before, but nothing helped....

Here is the code:

```
<div class="form-group form-group1">
                        <span class="mainh">some<br>text</span><br>
                        <span class="mainh1">some text</span><br>
                        <img src="img/logo/newlogo.png" class="img-responsive" pull-right>
                        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.form-group1{
margin-top: 100px;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: 400px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.mainh{
color: #000;
line-height:28px;
font-size: 43px;
font-family: Arial Black;
}

.mainh1{
color: #000;
font-size:25px;
font-family: Arial;
font-weight: 600;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pdpgwwp5/

Comment: use display:inline or float:left; Did you tried these css before?

Comment: Tryed but it didn't help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` and `<img>` are both inline elements, so they will be one line... if you remove the line breaks (`<br />`)

```css
.form-group1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainh {
  color: #000;
  line-height: 28px;
  font-size: 43px;
  font-family: Arial Black;
}
.mainh1 {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.form-group span {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
.form-group img {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-group1">
  <span class="mainh">some text</span>
  <span class="mainh1">some text</span>
  <img src="img/logo/newlogo.png" class="img-responsive pull-right" />
</div>
```

Note, I put `pull-right` inside the class attribute, I'm guessing that was a typo.

Comment: If you would like my help, then please explain what isn't working... they are on one line....

Comment: well I would like the texts "mainh and mainh1" to be on different rows and the image to be inline with them.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

```css
.form-group1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.mainh {
    color: #000;
    line-height:28px;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-family: Arial Black;
}
.mainh1 {
    color: #000;
    font-size:25px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-group1">
    <span class="mainh">some text</span>
    <span class="mainh1">some text</span>
    <img src="img/logo/newlogo.png" class="img-responsive" pull-right>
</div>
```

The 
 tag in your HTML causes the line break.